# HTML picture in div won't fill out body completely

Tags: html, css

I want to use a picture (jpg) as a background for my page.

This is how I tried to tackle the problem : 
Create the body, inside the body put a div with the id backgroundWallpaper. 
Inside the div i put the image.
The problem is though that it's completely filled out to the site (horizontal) and also to the top but at the bottom there is a small gap between the picture and the browser. I changed the body background to crimson red to demonstrate you the gap. I use the latest version of safari as my browser. This is my code :
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>name</title>
   <linkrel="stylesheet"
   href"http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="backgroundWallpaper">
    <img src=".../img/1.jpg" alt="image could not be loaded">
   </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

This is my css file

```
body {
 background: crimson;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#backgroundWallpaper img {
 max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: why don't you put the background image in the CSS? is there a reason to use a div and so on?

Comment: Agreed, Just use the picture as the background of the html element

Comment: How should I do that? I don't want to use any external frameworks...

Comment: Add: 'html {background: url(/picture.jpg)}' to your css files or in the same file between to '<style>' tags

Comment: @hudumudu it is just the background-image property of CSS... you can easilly find tons of examples of all the things you can do with that property: repeat image, stretch it and so on

Comment: then add also background-size:cover :)

Comment: i'd put it to body tag instead of html but i think it is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code for image to make image block element, image is a default  inline element and its has some attribute. That why you get extra space.

```
#backgroundWallpaper img{
  display:block
}
```

I hope it will helps you.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. Can you explain me why exactly this worked and what my bug was? I am quite new to web dev and only did python and swift before.

Comment: i advice that you also give it a `height: 100%;` also

Answer (score 0):

You are using `max-width: 100%;` , but this will not fill the DIV if your image is smaller than the DIV. Use `width: 100%`. Still, this does not guarantee that the heigth will fill the window height since it will stay in its original proportion.

Better would be to use the image as a background image for `body` and set `background-size: cover` for it

Answer (score 0):

when I add the css file directly to the html file, I do not see any spaces in firefox or chrome, but I do get that the image could not be loaded.  What size is the photo.  Without the photo dimensions, it may be difficult to resolve.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>name</title>
   <linkrel="stylesheet"
   href"http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="backgroundWallpaper">
    <img src=".../img/1.jpg" alt="image could not be loaded">
   </div>

<style>
body {
 background: crimson;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#backgroundWallpaper img {
 max-width: 100%;
}
</style>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use background to fit correctly as its explained [here](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

```css
body {
 background: crimson;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: url(http://placehold.it/350x150) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to see the image when you scroll down the page

```
#backgroundWallpaper{
  background-image: url(...);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;   
  height: 100vh; /* viewport height */
}
```